# Open a electron react js app from link in the browser

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have an electron app that has a recover password. When the email is sent, I want when the user clicks on the link on the email to redirect to the Electron App to show the Reset Password form, how can I handle it ?

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/launch-app-from-url-in-another-app) seems to have what you want.

In short: Register your own custom protocol, e.g. `my-app://` and your electron app as the handler for that protocol. Then send an email with a link that starts with it, like `my-app://reset-password`. The user should then be asked to allow opening the link with your app.

Comment: And on the event of app.on("open-url") can I redirect to a router of react that I have declared ?